# how to change a Python 2.7 installation package folder

Tags: python, windows, installation, package

I would like to install the PyPDF2 package (https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2)

I am on windows so I proceed like that :

`setup.py install`

But I got this message error :

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating C:\Program Files\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2
error: could not create "C:\Program Files\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyPDF2" : Access is denied
```

I have rights on my hard drive G but I couldn't find this windows path on the `setup.py` file.
Do you know can i change this path ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Strongly suggest checking out `virtualenv`. You can create a virtual python environment where you can install anything you please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `setup.py install --user` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to right-click the Command Prompt icon and select 'Run As Administrator'. This will let you install the package in the "C:\Program Files\Python\Python27... directory. --user is a great solution but it only installs for the current user, 'run as' installs for all users. 'run as' is useful if you use multiple accounts or are running a web service that needs the package.